# How do you download an image from the internet onto a file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image-upload, flutter-image, flutter-file

I'm making a Flutter project where an image is displayed in listview and the user can share, favourite or download the image. I'm stuck on the downloading part. Is it possible to save an image file onto the phone's storage for offline use?

What I want to happen is I can create and write an image file

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/$title.txt');
}

// Write an image by obtaining an image through a URL
```

and then be able to access it through

```
Image.file('$path/$title.txt')
```

Comment: Do you want to save it in gallery?

Comment: You haven't shared any of your code. Please check the question guidelines to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DeepakRor I don't mind, as long as I can access them through the app offline